# Имена контроллеров Yii под линукс

Tags: yii

Здравствуйте. Обнаружил, что CarMarkController.php не будет работать при обращении по адресу site/index.php?r=CarMark   - получим 404 (под линуксом). Если просто переименовать файл (не класс) в CarmarkController.php, то работает. Почему не работает, если файл с 2 заглавными?

В конфиге: url=>('caseSensitive'=>false,...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ нашел. 
Косяк с урлами в конфиге:
url=>('caseSensitive'=>false)...
так он со старта контроллер/экшн преобразует в нижний регистр и контроллер тоже ищет в нижнем, как и папку со вьюхами. Просто он рассчитывает, что все названия в нижнем регистре - тогда любой url пройдет (т.к. преобразуется в нижний)